# How to get stored procedure return value use C# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC and C# to build a member-signup system, and I call a stored procedure to verify member info in the controller.

If the member info are repetition, the stored procedure will return an error message and send a Viewbag to  front end to prompt where is repetition.

Now, not only can insert member info but also verifying data, but can't get stored procedure return value.

SP code

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tMember] WHERE mAccount = @mAccount AND mEmail = @mEmail AND mPhone=@mPhone)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tMember] (mAccount , mPwd , mEmail , mPhone , mName ) VALUES (@mAccount , @mPwd , @mEmail , @mPhone , @mName)
    --Messege : OK ==新增成功
    SET @msg = 'OK'
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tMember] WHERE mAccount = @mAccount)
BEGIN
--Messege : ErrorCode01 == 帳號重複
    SET @msg = 'ErrorCode01'
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tMember] WHERE mEmail = @mEmail)
BEGIN
--Messege : ErrorCode02 == 信箱重複
    SET @msg = 'ErrorCode02'
END
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tMember] WHERE mPhone = @mPhone)
BEGIN
--Messege : ErrorCode03 == 手機號碼重複
    SET @msg = 'ErrorCode03'
END
SELECT @msg AS result END
```

Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult Signup()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //使用post傳輸資料
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Signup(string mAccount, string mPwd, string mEmail ,string mPhone, string mName)
    {
        //tMember member = new tMember();
        //member.mAccount = mAccount;
        //member.mPwd = mPwd;
        //member.mEmail = mEmail;
        //member.mName = mName;
        ////新增會員資料
        //db.tMember.Add(member);
        //db.SaveChanges();
        db.sp_add_tMember(mAccount, mPwd, mEmail, mPhone, mName);

        // I dont know how to get SP return value send to front end and judge      
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Debugger should tell you everything you need. We can't without more info.

Comment: You need to post code so we know how you're calling the stored proc, but the standard way of returning data would either be the data itself (as a data table) or by using an output parameter.

Comment: Yep share the code please, sql call would be the most important piece in this scenario.

Comment: Ok ,I just upload my code and thank for everyone give me advice